# C# Interp. for Active Shape Models library in C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop, dllimport

Stasm (http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/index.html) is a C++ library for finding features on image, applying the concept of active shape models.

I am trying to use AsmSearchDll which is on stasm DLL (stasm_dll) like [this](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/opencv.html) on a C# project. In C++ the prototype is

```
void AsmSearchDll(
int *pnlandmarks, // out: number of landmarks, 0 if can't get landmarks
int landmarks[], // out: the landmarks, caller must allocate
const char image_name[], // in: used in internal error messages, if necessary
const char image_data[], // in: image data, 3 bytes per pixel if is_color
const int width, // in: the width of the image
const int height, // in: the height of the image
const int is_color, // in: 1 if RGB image, 0 if grayscale
const char conf_file0[], // in: 1st config filename, NULL for default
const char conf_file1[]); // in: 2nd config filename, NULL for default, "" for none
```

I am using this in C# with this

```
[DllImport(@"..\data\stasm_dll.dll")]
public static extern void AsmSearchDll(
        out int pnlandmarks, // out: number of landmarks, 0 if can't get landmarks
        out int[] landmarks, // out: the landmarks, caller must allocate
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string imagename, // in: used in internal error messages, if necessary
        byte[] imagedata, // in: image data, 3 bytes per pixel if is_color
        int width, // in: the width of the image
        int height, // in: the height of the image
        int is_color, // in: 1 if RGB image, 0 if grayscale
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string conf_file0, // in: 1st config filename, NULL for default
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string conf_file1 // in: 2nd config filename, NULL for default, "" for none
    );
```

The function starts to read the config files, but then it quits the program. I can't figure out what is going on. Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, how did you get it solved? Am facing the same issue, and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: i can't remember, sorry. But try to allocate pnlandmarks and landmarks first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to bind the same function to python unsuccessfully.

You have first to allocate the landmarks array and an int, before passing pointer to the function.

The function need a lot of configuration file in ../data/, be sure it is there.

The imagename string should actually be the FILEPATH of the image. No kidding. It loads it and process it whatever. Btw, imagedata must point to allocated memory to...