# Using Stasm with C# - DllImport / Interop

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392468/exporting-c-dll-to-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306649/c-sharp-interp-for-active-shape-models-library-in-c), unfortunately, the answers provided were not able to solve my problem. I'm using Stasm (http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/index.html) library in a C# application. Below is my code for calling the "AsmSearchDll" function.

```
        [DllImport(@"stasm\stasm_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern void AsmSearchDll
    (
        [Out] out Int32 pnlandmarks,
        [Out] out Int32[] landmarks,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String image_name,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String image_data,
        [In] Int32 width,
        [In] Int32 height,
        [In] Int32 is_color,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String conf_file0,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String conf_file1
    );

    public void SearchFacialFeatures()
    {
        string image_name = "image-5.jpg"; // imagePath;
        var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(image_name).Convert<Gray, byte>();

        int pnlandmarks = 0;
        var landmarks = new int[500];

        var imageData = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(image.MIplImage.imageData);
        int imgWidth = image.Width;
        int imgHeight = image.Height;
        int is_color = 1;
        string confile_file0 = Path.GetFullPath(@"data\mu-68-1d.conf");
        string config_file1 = Path.GetFullPath(@"data\mu-76-2d.conf");
        string sDataDir = @"\stasm\data";


        AsmSearchDll(out pnlandmarks, out landmarks, image_name, imageData, imgWidth, imgHeight, 1, null, null);

        MessageBox.Show(image_name);
    }
```

The problem is that the application processes stops when it gets to this line

```
AsmSearchDll(out pnlandmarks, out landmarks, image_name, imageData, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, null, null);
```

Initially the application quits whenever the AsmSearchDll function is called, after much playing around the code, that stopped. Now the application comes up, but the AsmSearchDll function is never processed. I could tell because I walked through the code with VS. The message box below the function is never reached.

I have a strong feeling that the the function is throwing internal error. The unfortunate part for me is that this is my first deal with Interop/DllImport.

My question is, what am I doing wrong, and how do I solve this problem? I've been on this for a day plus.

Edit: Added code for the unmanaged function

The signature of the unmanaged function

```
void AsmSearchDll (
int *pnlandmarks,          // out: number of landmarks, 0 if can't get landmarks
int landmarks[],           // out: the landmarks, caller must allocate
const char image_name[],   // in: used in internal error messages, if necessary
const char image_data[],   // in: image data, 3 bytes per pixel if is_color
const int width,           // in: the width of the image
const int height,          // in: the height of the image
const int is_color,        // in: 1 if RGB image, 0 if grayscale
const char conf_file0[],   // in: 1st config filename, NULL for default
const char conf_file1[])   // in: 2nd config filename, NULL for default, "" if none
```

C++ example for calling the function

```
    const char *image_name = "../data/test-image.jpg";

IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(image_name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(img == NULL) {
    printf("Error: Cannot open %s\n", image_name);
    return -1;
}
// sanity checks (AsmSearchDll assumes imageData is vector of b,r,g bytes)

if(img->nChannels != 3 || img->depth != IPL_DEPTH_8U ||
        img->origin != 0 || img->widthStep != 3 * img->width) {
    printf("Error: %s is an unrecognized image type\n", image_name);
    return -1;
}

// locate the facial landmarks with stasm

int nlandmarks;
int landmarks[500]; // space for x,y coords of up to 250 landmarks
AsmSearchDll(&nlandmarks, landmarks,
             image_name, img->imageData, img->width, img->height,
             1 /* is_color */, NULL /* conf_file0 */, NULL /* conf_file1 */);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the signature of the unmanaged function. How should you call it in C++ for example?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I've included code for the unmanaged function's signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this definition:

```
[DllImport(@"stasm\stasm_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern void AsmSearchDll
(
    [Out] out Int32 pnlandmarks,
    [Out] Int32[] landmarks,       // <-- the `out` keyword is removed
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String image_name,
    [In] IntPtr image_data,        // <-- should not be passed as string
    [In] Int32 width,
    [In] Int32 height,
    [In] Int32 is_color,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String conf_file0,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String conf_file1
);
```

I guess the main problem was the redundant `out` keyword on `landmarks`, that causes the parameter to be passed as a *pointer to array*, which means *pointer to pointer to int*. What you need is a *pointer to int*.

Also passing a byte array as string could corrupt the contents of the bytes (`image_data` parameter). Now there is no need to use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` function. Pass `image.MIplImage.imageData` directly to the function.

Let me know if it works or not. I cannot test it.

Comment: I've modified my definition to this, but it's now back to the previous behavior. The application quits when it gets to the "AsmSearchDll" function.

Comment: Don't you get any exception?

Comment: No, it's not throwing any exception. I even tried running the .exe application from the bin directory to see if it will throw exception, but nothing happened. Could this be caused by unspecified dependent dlls?

Comment: If you have the code for the original dll (I guess you have), you can debug it another way from unmanaged code. So you can check what happens it the unmanaged side.

Comment: @Syma If you can upload a working sample project somewhere, I can have a look at it.

Comment: The file is a bit large for me to upload to a server. I just compiled the opencv c++ example that came with the library, everything appears to work fine. I also copied all generated dlls including "stasm_dll.dll" with the hope that the version am using in my application could be the wrong one. But still no luck.

Comment: I've been able to get it to work. I created a sample console application to see if error will display on console, and it did. The problem was, the function was trying to access ..\data\ folder. I had it in the debug directory where my dll and application resides. moving it one level up got the issue solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your program is trying to look for certain files in ../data/%filename% which leads to looking inside the bin folder that contains Debug and Release folders and your working directory is actually either Debug or Release depending on your configuration. This is why the program returns with a code 0x01 and an error.A simple solution is to copy the data folder containing all required files to the parent folder of your Debug or Release folder, this should be a fast solution or you could look into fixing this by modifying the folder paths that the dll looks for those folders.

This problem happens because the paths are hardcoded.